# Error in file CrossGeeks / ToolbarItemBadgeSample / BarButtonItemExtensions in Xamarin IOS, + Add Badge issue In IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, badge

Error hits this file . The app closes .

This happens when i open the app for the second time . If the app is already logged in and the master page is opened directly on which the badge is present.

Also add badge does not update the badge in IOS , works perfectly in android .

[image]

Comment: barButtonItem.ValueForKey(new NSString(@"view")) as UIView; .  This returns null in View upon opening the application second time .

Comment: Hi, not too much understanding the `barButtonItem`. You could share the related code of forms and the full code of `BarButtonItemExtensions.cs`?

Comment: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/ToolbarItemBadgeSample . Code is picked up from this

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link, I will check that whether can reproduce it in my local site.

Comment: Hi, I have checked this sample in local site, not finding the same phenomenon in iOS device. Maybe you have modified some part code of your project, it will occur the different result.